# Can't obtain solution for the variable gamma1, what's wrong?

Tags: maple

I want to use the following code

```
f := sqrt(7200*8200)*10^6: 
Ig := 0, 9330; Ug := 13.134: 
f_gr := 10^10:
r_e := .8: 
L_e := .5*10^(-9): 
C_e := 2.5*10^(-12): 
Cka := .4*10^(-12): 
Ckp := .8*10^(-12): 
L_b := .3*10^(-9): 
I_0 := I*f*Ig*(cos(.4*f/f_gr)+I*sin(.4*f/f_gr))/(f_gr*gamma1):
I_e := I_0+Ig:
U_e := I_e*(r_e+I*(2*Pi*f*L_e)):
U_p := -I*(1-gamma1)*I_0/(2*Pi*f*C_e):
Uska := Ug+U_p:
Iska := I*(2*Pi*f*Cka*Uska):
Irb := I_0+Iska:
Urb := 2.8*Irb:
Uskp := Urb+Uska:
Iskp := I*(2*Pi*f*Ckp*Uskp):
Irk := Uskp/773.5:
Ib := Irb+Iskp+Irk:
Ulb := I*(2*Pi*f*L_b*Ib):
Uv := U_e+Ulb+Urb+U_p:
Ik := Ig-Iska-Iskp-Irk:
Uk := Ug-U_e:
```

to solve `Re(Uk)*Re(Ik)+Im(Uk)*Im(Ik)=0.186` for gamma1 (I is for imaginary unit). But this doesn't work. I've tried to use brute force, assigning some numbers to gamma1 and then finding `Re(Uk)*Re(Ik)+Im(Uk)*Im(Ik)`, but I can't obtain a number anyway. Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has an apparent mistake in the definition of `Ig`, to which you have assigned the expression sequence `0, 9330`.

Perhaps you intended `Ig:=0.9330` instead.

```
restart;
f := sqrt(7200*8200)*10^6: 
Ig := 0.9330:
Ug := 13.134: 
f_gr := 10^10:
r_e := .8: 
L_e := .5*10^(-9): 
C_e := 2.5*10^(-12): 
Cka := .4*10^(-12): 
Ckp := .8*10^(-12): 
L_b := .3*10^(-9): 
I_0 := I*f*Ig*(cos(.4*f/f_gr)+I*sin(.4*f/f_gr))/(f_gr*gamma1):
I_e := I_0+Ig:
U_e := I_e*(r_e+I*(2*Pi*f*L_e)):
U_p := -I*(1-gamma1)*I_0/(2*Pi*f*C_e):
Uska := Ug+U_p:
Iska := I*(2*Pi*f*Cka*Uska):
Irb := I_0+Iska:
Urb := 2.8*Irb:
Uskp := Urb+Uska:
Iskp := I*(2*Pi*f*Ckp*Uskp):
Irk := Uskp/773.5:
Ib := Irb+Iskp+Irk:
Ulb := I*(2*Pi*f*L_b*Ib):
Uv := U_e+Ulb+Urb+U_p:
Ik := Ig-Iska-Iskp-Irk:
Uk := Ug-U_e:
```

And now,

```
solve(Re(Uk)*Re(Ik)+Im(Uk)*Im(Ik)=0.186, {gamma1});

       {gamma1 = -0.9296926790 - 0.6316639400 I}
```